# Facebook app android post on wall

Tags: android, facebook

I registered an Android app with Facebook but I'm having a hard time posting on the user's wall and on the user's friends wall. For example, when I post to my own wall from the app, I'm the only one who can see the post. And when I post on any of my friend's wall, I get no errors but the post doesn't appear in his wall. The app asks for the permission "publish_stream" so in the beginning, I should be able to do it. I've thoroughly been searching on the Facebook documentation and on the web but I haven't found any solution to the problem. That's the code I execute to post:

//me

`facebook.dialog(Activity, "feed", new PostDialogListener());`

//friend of mine

`Bundle params = new Bundle();`

`params.putString("to", "id_friend");`

`facebook.dialog(Activity, "feed", params new PostDialogListener());`

Any comments would be highly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: are you using publish_stream permission in your `authorize` method?

Comment: I finally found it. The problem was that sandbox mode was enabled!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found it. The problem was that **sandbox was enabled** in the app settings. Once I disabled it, I could post perfectly on my friends wall and on my own too.